# Replace double backslash in string literal with single backslash

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to print a string that contains double backslash (one to escape the other) such that only one of the backslashes are printed. I thought this would happen automatically, but I must be missing some detail.

I have this little snippet:

```
for path in self.tokenized:
    pdb.set_trace()
    print(self.tokenized[path])
```

When I debug with that `pdb.set_trace()` I can see that my strings have double backslashes, and then I enter continue to print the remainder and it prints that same thing.

```
> /home/kendall/Development/path-parser/tokenize_custom.py(82)print_tokens()
-> print(self.tokenized[path])
(Pdb) self.tokenized[path]
['c:', '\\home', '\\kendall', '\\Desktop', '\\home\\kendall\\Desktop']
(Pdb) c
['c:', '\\home', '\\kendall', '\\Desktop', '\\home\\kendall\\Desktop']
```

Note that I'm writing a parser that parses Windows file paths -- thus the backslashes.

This is what it looks like to run the program:

```
kendall@kendall-XPS-8500:~/Development/path-parser$ python main.py -f c:\\home\\kendall\\Desktop
```

Comment: Use `print(','.join(self.tokenized[path]))` instead. Right now, your strings are not being `print`'d

Comment: .. but rather for strings nested in lists, you get `repr(string)`, which has the backslash escaped.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget is there a clean way to add square brackets around it as if it were a list

Comment: `print("[{}]".format(','.join(self.tokenized[path])))`

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is that you're `print`ing a list, which only knows one way to stringify its contents: `repr`.  `repr` is only designed for debugging use. Idiomatically, when possible (classes are a notable exception), it outputs a syntactically valid python expression that can be directly fed into the interpretter to reproduce the original object - hence the escaped backslashes.

Instead, you need to loop through each list, and print each string individually.

You can use `str.join()` to do this for you.

To get the exact same output, minus the doubled backslashes, you'd need to do something like:

```
print("[{0}]".format(", ".join(self.tokenized[path])))
```